# No audio while editing video

Tags: tracking, audio, timeline

I am trying to edit my video in blender and I soon realized there is no audio. By looking at other questions similar to this I turned on the audio codec, made sure audio was on in user prefences, and put the video on AV-sync. I also checked sure to make sure the video did have audio. [image: camera tracking setup] As you can see in the image I did set up the audio codec, I'm just not sure if it is correct. To clarify, I need to get audio in my video but I can't. This is different from similar questions because they are concerning after render, mine is not.

I am using Blender version 2.77 on windows ten with a video converted from .Mov to .Mp4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Audio playback doesn't work in the Movie clip editor.
For Video editing you should use The Video Sequence Editor.

Comment: I still get no sound even when I am in Video Editor. All I did was Add>clip>"My_Clip"

Comment: @Sammy that's strange, try again with *add movie* and make sure *sound* is enabled when you select your video file.

Comment: that worked, thanks! But I am trying to chroma key in blender, which uses camera tracking and compositing. Now I have two seperate videos, one in video editing and one in compositing that are out of sync. Is there any way to  get- audio in composting or chroma keying in video editing?

Comment: you do the tracking with no audio in the clip editor , then you do the compositing in the compositor with nodes, then you finally import everything to the video sequence editor. I hope i didn't confuse you too much.